# Having trouble when using a piecewise function

Tags: function-construction, piecewise

I am trying to define a function where H1[x_]= a previously derived value if 0 < x <100 and H1[x_]=x if x>100 so I have used the following piecewise function:
H1[x_]:=Piecewise[{{Evaluate[y[x] /. s],0 < x < 100},{x, x > 100}}].
However when I plot this H1[x_] function it gives the graph after entering the following
Plot[H1[x],{x,1,200}]
Does anyone know why it is not taking the value of H1[x_]=x after x=100? 
thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: ... what is `s`?

Comment: s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == f[x, y[x], -1.5, 1.25, 2, 1], y[100] == 99}, 
  y, {x, 1,100.005}] where f is defined as:

Comment: f[x_, y_, m_, n_, p_, K_] := (p x^(p - 1) y ((m + 1) (x/y)^n - (n + 1) (x/y)^m))/(((m + 1) (n + 1) x^p - n m K y) ((x/y)^n - (x/y)^m))

Comment: Thank you Max Toon. Please update your question with the information about `f` and `s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Evaluate[y[x] /. s[[1]]]` instead of `Evaluate[y[x] /. s]` to get

[image]